Conversion from body frame to NED frame
I have following Python code:
# Define rotation matrix from body frame to NED frame
R = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1]])

# Extract angular velocity and acceleration columns
angular_velocity = df[[8, 9,10]].values
acceleration = df[[5, 6, 7]].values

# Convert angular velocity and acceleration to NED frame
angular_velocity_ned = np.dot(angular_velocity, R.T)
acceleration_ned = np.dot(acceleration, R.T)

This code is trying to convert coordinates from body frame to NED frame by taking dot product with rotation matrix R. I do not get why it has chosen this specific matrix value for R (that is [[1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1]]). I understand it is essentially trying to flip y and z coordinates, while leaving x coordinates untouched. In other words, it's trying to do a 180 degree rotation around the  X-axis. But how does it result in a transformation from body frame to NED frame?
To clarify, the code seems to work but I don't know the source of the code. I found this in a codebase that I inherited from someone who used to work on the project. He has left the project already and I have no documentation as such. I want explanation as to how/why the code works.

This might be useful: Appendix C: Coordinate Transformations
